# Tkinter: Calling material from combobox after adding a row

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, binding, row

1. In the given code if I select the material in the 6th row or the last row then it is showing in that respective row.
2. If I add any row afer that and select the material, then also it is showing the material in that last row for example it would be 7th row here.
3. However, if I select the material in 2nd row firstly, then it is showing the material in the 2nd row.
4. Now comes the devil, if I add a row after 2nd row and a new row has been added at 3rd position. If I select the material in this layer then the material selected or properties related to that will be showed in the nect row which is 4th.

I have attached the screenshots also.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial


def open_layers_window(root):
    layers_window = Toplevel(root)
    layers_window.title("Substrate Data")
    layers_window.geometry('1800x400')
    layers_window.resizable(True, True)

    # Specify the path to your Excel file
    excel_file_path = 'Substances Database.xlsx'

    # Load the Excel file
    excel_data = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file_path)

    # Get the names of all sheets in the Excel file
    sheet_names = excel_data.sheet_names

    # Choose the active sheet (you mentioned one sheet is active)
    active_sheet_name = excel_data.sheet_names[1]  # Change this based on your actual sheet name

    # Read the data from the active sheet
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_data, sheet_name=active_sheet_name, index_col=0)

    # Extract material names from the 'substrate' sheet
    material_names = df.columns[2:].tolist()  # Assuming material names start from column 2

    # Specify the column names
    column_names = ['Layer\nNo.', 'Layer\nname', 'Material', 'Description', 'Grammage\n[g/m\u00b2]', 'Thickness\n[µm]',
                    'Density\n[kg/m\u00b3]', 'Specific heat capacity\n[kJ/kg.K]', 'Heat conductivity\n[W/m.K]',
                    'Starting Temperature\n[°C]']

  


    global density_entries
    global specific_heat_capacity_entries
    global heat_conductivity_entries
    global description_entries
    global grammage_entries
    global thickness_entries

    density_entries = []
    specific_heat_capacity_entries = []
    heat_conductivity_entries = []
    description_entries = []
    grammage_entries = []
    thickness_entries = []

    i = 5

    rows = []

    def setup_ui(root):

        def calculate_grammage(row_num, density_value):
            try:
                density_entry = density_entries[row_num]
                thickness_entry = thickness_entries[row_num]
                grammage_entry = grammage_entries[row_num]

                # Get the values from the entry fields
                density_str = density_entry.get().strip()
                thickness_str = thickness_entry.get().strip()
                grammage_str = grammage_entry.get().strip()

                

                # Check if density is not modified
                if density_str:
                    density=float(density_str)

                    #if thickness_str and not grammage_str:
                        # Calculate grammage if only thickness is given
                        #thickness = float(thickness_str)
                        #grammage = density * thickness / 1000
                        #grammage_entry.delete(0, END)
                        #grammage_entry.insert(0, f'{grammage:.2f}')

                    #elif grammage_str and not thickness_str:
                        # Calculate thickness if only grammage is given
                        #grammage = float(grammage_str)
                        #thickness = (grammage * 1000) / density
                        #thickness_entry.delete(0, END)
                        #thickness_entry.insert(0, f'{thickness:.2f}')

                    #elif grammage_str and thickness_str:
                        # Update density if both thickness and grammage are provided
                        #thickness = float(thickness_str)
                        #grammage = float(grammage_str)
                        #new_density = grammage / (thickness / 1000)
                        #density_entry.delete(0, END)
                        #density_entry.insert(0, f'{new_density:.2f}')

                    if thickness_str and not grammage_str:
                        #Calculate grammage if only thickness is given
                        thickness = float(thickness_str)
                        grammage = density * thickness / 1000
                        grammage_entry.delete(0, END)
                        grammage_entry.insert(0, f'{grammage:.2f}')

                    elif grammage_str and not thickness_str:
                        # Calculate thickness if only grammage is given
                        grammage = float(grammage_str)
                        thickness = (grammage * 1000) / density
                        thickness_entry.delete(0, END)
                        thickness_entry.insert(0, f'{thickness:.2f}')

                    elif grammage_str and thickness_str:
                        # Update density if both thickness and grammage are provided
                        thickness = float(thickness_str)
                        grammage = float(grammage_str)
                        new_density = grammage / (thickness / 1000)
                        density_entry.delete(0, END)
                        density_entry.insert(0, f'{new_density:.2f}')

           
                    
                    if thickness_str and not grammage_str:
                        # Calculate grammage if only thickness is given
                        if thickness_str:
                            thickness = float(thickness_str)
                            grammage = float(density) * thickness / 1000
                            grammage_entry.delete(0, END)
                            grammage_entry.insert(0, f'{grammage:.2f}')

                    elif grammage_str and not thickness_str:
                        if grammage_str:
                        #Calculate thickness if only grammage is given
                            grammage = float(grammage_str)
                            thickness = (grammage * 1000) / density
                            thickness_entry.delete(0, END)
                            thickness_entry.insert(0, f'{thickness:.2f}')

                    elif grammage_str and thickness_str:
                        # Update density if both thickness and grammage are provided
                        thickness = float(thickness_str)
                        grammage = float(grammage_str)
                        new_density = grammage / (thickness / 1000)
                        density_entry.delete(0, END)
                        density_entry.insert(0, f'{new_density:.2f}')

                       
                    #else:
                    #    # Handle the case when both thickness and grammage are filled
                    #    grammage_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                    #    grammage_entries[row_num].insert(0, "")
                    #    thickness_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                    #    thickness_entries[row_num].insert(0,"")
                
                else:
                    # Handle the case when density is not provided
                    print("Please enter a valid density value.")
         
                  
            except ValueError:
                # Handle the case when conversion to float fails
                print("Please enter valid numerical values for Thickness and Grammage.")


        def on_combobox_select(event, row_num):
            selected_header = event.widget.get()

            
            if selected_header:
                density_value = df.loc['Density', selected_header] if selected_header else 0
                density_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                density_entries[row_num].insert(0, density_value)

                Specific_heat_capacity_value = df.loc['Specific heat capacity', selected_header]
                specific_heat_capacity_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                specific_heat_capacity_entries[row_num].insert(0, Specific_heat_capacity_value)

                Heat_conductivity_value = df.loc['Heat conductivity', selected_header]
                heat_conductivity_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                heat_conductivity_entries[row_num].insert(0, Heat_conductivity_value)

                description_value = df.loc['Additional description', selected_header]
                description_entries[row_num].delete(0, END)
                description_entries[row_num].insert(0, description_value)

                # Trigger grammage calculation when density is updated
                calculate_grammage(row_num, density_value)

                on_thickness_focus_out(row_num)

           

        def on_thickness_focus_out(row_num):
            density_value = float(density_entries[row_num].get().strip()) if density_entries[row_num].get().strip() else 0
            # Trigger grammage calculation when thickness is updated (on focus out)
            calculate_grammage(row_num, density_value)

        def delete_row(row_num):
            if row_num < len(rows):
                # Remove the row from the list
                deleted_row = rows.pop(row_num)

                # Remove the widgets from the grid
                for widget in deleted_row:
                    widget.grid_forget()

                # Rearrange the rows after the deleted row
                for i in range(row_num, len(rows)):
                    for col_index in range(len(column_names) + 2):  # Adjust column index for the buttons
                        rows[i][col_index].grid(row=i + 1, column=col_index)

                # Remove the last empty row if exists
                if rows and not any(rows[-1]):
                    rows[-1][0].destroy()  # Destroy the "Add Row" button
                    rows.pop()  # Remove the last empty row from the list
        
        def add_row(row_num):
            # Create a new row with entries, buttons, and delete button
            items = []
            for j in range(len(column_names)):
                if j == 2:
                    # Material ComboBox
                    material_var = StringVar()
                    material_combobox = ttk.Combobox(layers_window, textvariable=material_var, values=material_names)
                    material_combobox.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    density_value = df.loc['Density', material_combobox.get()] if material_combobox.get() else 0
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_combobox_select(event, row))
                    items.append(material_combobox)

                elif j == 3:
                    # Description Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    description_entries.append(entry)

                elif j == 4:
                    # Grammage Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    grammage_entries.append(entry)
                    grammage_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    grammage_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                    lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                                float(
                                                                                                    density_entries[
                                                                                                        row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                if density_entries[
                                                                                                    row_num].get().strip() else 0))

                elif j == 5:
                    # Thickness Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    thickness_entries.append(entry)
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                    lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                               float(
                                                                                                    density_entries[
                                                                                                        row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                if density_entries[
                                                                                                   row_num].get().strip() else 0))

                elif j == 6:
                    # Density Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    density_entries.append(entry)

                    # After density entry is created, get the density value for the selected material
                    selected_material = material_combobox.get()
                    density_value = df.loc['Density', selected_material] if selected_material else 0

                    # Now bind the events with the correct density_value
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_combobox_select(event, row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                    lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                                float(
                                                                                                    density_entries[
                                                                                                        row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                if density_entries[
                                                                                                    row_num].get().strip() else 0))

                elif j == 7:
                    # Specific Heat Capacity Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    specific_heat_capacity_entries.append(entry)

                elif j == 8:
                    # Heat Conductivity Entry
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    heat_conductivity_entries.append(entry)

                else:
                    # Other Entries
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)  # Adjust column index to start from 0
                    items.append(entry)

            # Create Add Row and Delete Row buttons
            add_button = Button(layers_window, text="Add Row", command=partial(add_row, row_num + 1))
            add_button.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=len(column_names))  # Adjust column index for the button
            items.append(add_button)

            delete_button = Button(layers_window, text="Delete Row",command=partial(delete_row,row_num))
            delete_button.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=len(column_names) + 1)  # Adjust column index for the button
            items.append(delete_button)

            # Shift down the rows below the add button
            for i in range(len(rows) - 1, row_num - 1, -1):
                for col_index in range(len(column_names) + 2):  # Adjust column index for the buttons
                    rows[i][col_index].grid_forget()  # Remove entries and buttons from the grid

            # Insert the new row at the specified position
            rows.insert(row_num, items)

            # Place the entries and buttons back on the grid
            for i in range(row_num, len(rows)):
                for col_index in range(len(column_names) + 2):  # Adjust column index for the buttons
                    rows[i][col_index].grid(row=i + 1, column=col_index)







        for col_index, col_name in enumerate(column_names):
            label = Label(layers_window, text=col_name)
            label.grid(row=0, column=col_index)

        for row_num in range(i):
            items = []
            for j in range(len(column_names)):
                if j == 2:
                    material_var = StringVar()
                    material_combobox = ttk.Combobox(layers_window, textvariable=material_var, values=material_names)
                    material_combobox.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    density_value = df.loc['Density', material_combobox.get()] if material_combobox.get() else 0
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_combobox_select(event, row))
                    items.append(material_combobox)

                elif j == 3:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    description_entries.append(entry)

                elif j == 4:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    grammage_entries.append(entry)
                    grammage_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    grammage_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                    lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                                 float(
                                                                                                     density_entries[
                                                                                                         row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                 if density_entries[
                                                                                                    row_num].get().strip() else 0))
                elif j == 5:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    thickness_entries.append(entry)
                    # Attach on_thickness_focus_out to the thickness entry field's FocusOut event
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                     lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                                  float(
                                                                                                      density_entries[
                                                                                                          row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                  if density_entries[
                                                                                                     row_num].get().strip() else 0))

                elif j == 6:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    density_entries.append(entry)

                    # After density entry is created, get the density value for the selected material
                    selected_material = material_combobox.get()
                    density_value = df.loc['Density', selected_material] if selected_material else 0

                    # Now bind the events with the correct density_value
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_combobox_select(event, row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event, row=row_num: on_thickness_focus_out(row))
                    thickness_entries[row_num].bind("<FocusOut>",
                                                     lambda event, row=row_num: calculate_grammage(row_num,
                                                                                                  float(
                                                                                                      density_entries[
                                                                                                          row_num].get().strip())
                                                                                                  if density_entries[
                                                                                                     row_num].get().strip() else 0))

                elif j == 7:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    specific_heat_capacity_entries.append(entry)

                elif j == 8:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)
                    items.append(entry)
                    heat_conductivity_entries.append(entry)

                else:
                    v = StringVar()
                    entry = Entry(layers_window, textvariable=v)
                    v.set(f'Col{j}')
                    entry.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=j)  # Adjust column index to start from 0
                    items.append(entry)

            # Create a button at the end of the row
            button = ttk.Button(layers_window, text="Add Row", command=partial(add_row, row_num + 1))
            button.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=len(column_names))  # Adjust column index for the button
            items.append(button)

            delete_button = ttk.Button(layers_window, text="Delete Row",command=partial(delete_row,row_num))
            delete_button.grid(row=row_num + 1, column=len(column_names) + 1)  # Adjust column index for the button
            items.append(delete_button)


            # Insert the new row at the specified position
            rows.append(items)

    setup_ui(layers_window)
```

[both the layers are given the inputs for the material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFLoq.jpg)
[a new row has been created after clicking add row button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv9a3.jpg)
[material in next row after I have added a new row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGqDY.jpg)

I would be really grateful if someone can help me in this issue.

I try to change the binding of events or calling of row_num. But it doesn't get solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `row_num` passed to `add_row()` or `delete_row()` will be incorrect after adding or deleting row.  So you need to get the correct `row_num` using the grid information of the related widgets.
2. `.insert(...)` instead of `.append(...)` should be used to add items to those *arrays* (`density_entries`, `description_entries`, etc) inside `add_row()`.
3. item in those *arrays* should be removed as well inside `delete_row()`

Below are the changes required:

```py
def open_layers_window(root):
    ...

    def setup_ui(root):
        ...

        def on_combobox_select(event):  # removed row_num argument
            # get correct row_num (index to arrays)
            row_num = event.widget.grid_info()["row"] - 1
            ...

        ...

        def delete_row(button):  # changed argument row_num to button widget
            # at least keep one row
            if len(rows) == 1:
                return
            # get the correct row_num (index to arrays)
            row_num = button.grid_info()["row"] - 1
            if row_num < len(rows):
                # Remove the row from the list
                deleted_row = rows.pop(row_num)
                # remove from other arrays as well
                density_entries.pop(row_num)
                specific_heat_capacity_entries.pop(row_num)
                heat_conductivity_entries.pop(row_num)
                description_entries.pop(row_num)
                grammage_entries.pop(row_num)
                thickness_entries.pop(row_num)

                # Remove the widgets from the grid
                for widget in deleted_row:
                    widget.destroy()  # destroy the widget instead of hiding it
                ...

        def add_row(button):  # changed argument row_num to button widget
            # get correct row_num (index to arrays)
            row_num = button.grid_info()["row"]
            ...
            for j in range(len(column_names)):
                if j == 2:
                    ...
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", on_combobox_select)
                    items.append(material_combobox)

                elif j == 3:
                    ...
                    #description_entries.append(entry)
                    description_entries.insert(row_num, entry) # use insert()

                elif j == 4:
                    ...
                    #grammage_entries.append(entry)
                    grammage_entries.insert(row_num, entry) # use insert()
                    ...

                elif j == 5:
                    ...
                    #thickness_entries.append(entry)
                    thickness_entries.insert(row_num, entry)
                    ...

                elif j == 6:
                    ...
                    #density_entries.append(entry)
                    density_entries.insert(row_num, entry)
                    ...

                elif j == 7:
                    ...
                    #specific_heat_capacity_entries.append(entry)
                    specific_heat_capacity_entries.insert(row_num, entry)

                elif j == 8:
                    ...
                    #heat_conductivity_entries.append(entry)
                    heat_conductivity_entries.insert(row_num, entry)
                
                ...

            # Create Add Row and Delete Row buttons
            add_button = Button(layers_window, text="Add Row")
            # pass button widget to add_row()
            add_button.config(command=partial(add_row, add_button))
            ...
            delete_button = Button(layers_window, text="Delete Row")
            # pass button widget to delete_row()
            delete_button.config(command=partial(delete_row, delete_button))
            ...

        ...
            
        for row_num in range(i):
            items = []
            for j in range(len(column_names)):
                if j == 2:
                    ...
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", on_combobox_select)
                    ...
                ...
                elif j == 6:
                    ...
                    material_combobox.bind("<FocusIn>", on_combobox_select)
                    ...
            ...

            # Create a button at the end of the row
            button = ttk.Button(layers_window, text="Add Row")
            # pass button widget to add_row()
            button.config(command=partial(add_row, button))
            ...
            delete_button = ttk.Button(layers_window, text="Delete Row")
            # pass button widget to delete_row()
            delete_button.config(command=partial(delete_row, button))
            ...
        ...
```

*Note that the above changes fix the *adding* and *deleting* of row.  There are still other functions using `row_num` as argument which may need to be fixed as well.*